# Identify Windows DirectX game about building a manufacturing business

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, windows-98

I'm trying to find the name of a game that I played in the mid-to-late 1990's. Here's what I remember about it:

- What I played was a demo version, that came on a CD along a bunch of other demos. They were all Windows DirectX games, and the disk seemed to be part of Microsoft's push to get people to consider Windows "the ultimate gaming platform". I assume it must have been for Windows 95 or Windows 98, as they were trying to get DirectX to be a thing. I don't know where I got the CD from, but it probably came with a magazine or something. I think there was a 3-D space that one walked around in to select what game demo to play.
- In this game, you were the manager/owner of a manufacturing factory. You needed to buy machines that could change raw materials into finished goods, and hire workers to operate the machines. You could also hire workers to do other jobs, like sales and marketing.
- There were a lot of possible raw materials, finished goods, and machine options. Part of the challenge was to look at "the market" and figure out what products made the most sense to try to produce.
- The machines and workers needed to be physically laid out on the factory floor. It was an overhead view. (I'm guessing it was probably isometric.) When you "ran" the factory for day, you would see the workers running around and putting things in and taking things out of the machines.
- If you failed to mark certain areas, like near the inputs of machines, with "warning area" yellow, then the workers would be much more likely to get mangled by the machines, which cost a lot of money and was generally a bad thing. There were other areas that needed to be marked too, like a place to store incoming and outgoing product.
- There were options of how much money to start the game with, with there being a smaller amount of money from something like an inheritance, to a larger amount of money but it was a loan that needed to be paid back.

I'm curious about the demo as a whole and other things on it, if you happen to know what demo disk I'm talking about, but for now I'm really just looking for the name of this specific game that was on it. (Though if there's a legal source to buy the demo or the full game still, I'd be interested in knowing that, too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like [Free Enterprise](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/free-enterprise), which is included as a demo on [the Games Sampler 2 for Windows 95](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/games-sampler-2-for-windows-95) CD which Microsoft published in 1996. The CD has a menu where you walk around a spaceship, and the game demos are featured on pedestals which allow you to launch them.

The demo CD is [available on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/GamesSampler2ForWindows95Version2).